# SharePoint Online - Conditional Formulas For Columns

Tags: conditional

I've finally convinced management to let me build some decent apps with SharePoint Online. I am trying out the stock issue tracker and I have a question about  Column Validation.

We have a column called Error. My boss asked if we could make a formula that if the Error is "Backorder", then make the Column called "Cost" (which is a currency field) to = $0.00.

I've tried to research proper formula building but can't make much sense of it.

The column validation option is under lists and advanced...and looks like this:

[image: Formulas]

I've tried this but it said I can't change another column:

=IF([Reason]="Backorder", "$0.00")

Any tips or suggestions? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As James said, a Validation Formula is intended to prevent the save of an item.

Two options for what you are describing:

1. Create a Calculated Column that "corrects" the cost. (Maybe name this column Final Cost.)

   =IF( [Reason]="Backorder", 0, [Cost] )

The Calculated Column would display either a zero or the value entered in the Cost column.

2. Create a SharePoint Designer workflow that checks the Reason Column and sets the value of Cost to 0 if Reason equals "Backorder".

Comment: Number One worked for me. Thank you SO much. New to SharePoint Online but I do like what I see so far. I just have to convince management.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is not Column Validation, but actually using a [calculated column](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3).

Column validation cant set the value of columns. It can only block the saving of an item if the validation formula fails.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for helping me clear this up.